# Unable to Install Package via Yum

Tags: elasticsearch, yum

I am having a strange issue where i am struggling to install latest elasticsearch package via yum. There is nothing in /etc/yum.conf to be excluded. Contents of /etc/yum.repos.d/elasticsearch.repo is listed below

```
[elasticsearch-6.x]
name=Elasticsearch repository for 6.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
```

It appears that yum can't find it. I have tried yum clean all, yum makecache etc and system reboot as well but nothing helped.

I am running this on AmazonLinux1. Interestingly I can install it if i fetch the rpm manually.

```
# yum --disableexcludes=all --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="elasticsearch-6.x" list available | grep elasticsearch
apm-server.i686                        6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
apm-server.x86_64                      6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
auditbeat.i686                         6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
auditbeat.x86_64                       6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
filebeat.i686                          6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
filebeat.x86_64                        6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
heartbeat-elastic.i686                 6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
heartbeat-elastic.x86_64               6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
journalbeat.i686                       6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
journalbeat.x86_64                     6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
kibana-oss.x86_64                      6.3.0-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
logstash.noarch                        1:6.5.3-1               elasticsearch-6.x
metricbeat.i686                        6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
metricbeat.x86_64                      6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
packetbeat.i686                        6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
packetbeat.x86_64                      6.5.3-1                 elasticsearch-6.x
```

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/yum` returns a `404` error for me - along with all the other links so I presume directory listing is forbidden. Have you tried `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.5.4.rpm` & what happens when you try `yum search elasticsearch` against that repo?

Answer (score 0):

It was the yum versionlock. Once we deleted the versoin locks it all looks ok.